# Why my comments between /* and */ in my SCSS file are taken into account?

Tags: sass

`Gulp watch` yields errors related to code between `/*` and `*/` in my `scss` file, although I've read that this is a regular way of commenting in `SASS`. Any idea why I have this problem?

[EDIT] 
Error:

```
Error: Undefined variable: "$sm-breakpoint".
        on line 42 of assets/styles/core/_media-queries.scss
>> /*
   ^
[23:30:48] Finished 'styles' after 14 ms
```

Content of my `scss` file:

```
$screen: "only screen";
$landscape: "#{$screen} and (orientation: landscape)";
$portrait: "#{$screen} and (orientation: portrait)";

/* Breakpoints */
$mq_600: "#{$screen} and (max-width: 600px)";
$mq_768: "#{$screen} and (max-width: 768px)";
$mq_1000: "#{$screen} and (max-width: 1000px)";
$mq_1024: "#{$screen} and (max-width: 1023px)";
$mq_1200: "#{$screen} and (max-width: 1200px)";
$mq_1300: "#{$screen} and (max-width: 1300px)";
$mq_1400: "#{$screen} and (max-width: 1400px)";
$mq_1500: "#{$screen} and (max-width: 1500px)";
$mq_1460: "#{$screen} and (max-width: 1460px)";

@mixin mq_600 {
  @media #{$mq_600} {@content}
}
@mixin mq_768 {
  @media #{$mq_768} {@content}
}
@mixin mq_1000 {
  @media #{$mq_1000} {@content}
}
@mixin mq_1024 {
  @media #{$mq_1024} {@content}
}
@mixin mq_1200 {
  @media #{$mq_1200} {@content}
}
@mixin mq_1300 {
  @media #{$mq_1300} {@content}
}
@mixin mq_1400 {
  @media #{$mq_1400} {@content}
}
@mixin mq_1500 {
  @media #{$mq_1500} {@content}
}

/* Up - mobile fist approach */
/*
$sm-up: "#{$screen} and (min-width: #{$sm-breakpoint + 1})";  
$md-up: "#{$screen} and (min-width: #{$md-breakpoint + 1})";  
$lg-up: "#{$screen} and (min-width: #{$lg-breakpoint + 1})";  
$xlg-up: "#{$screen} and (min-width: #{$xlg-breakpoint + 1})"; 

@mixin sm-up {
  @media #{$sm-up} {@content}
}
@mixin md-up {
  @media #{$md-up} {@content}
}
@mixin lg-up {
  @media #{$lg-up} {@content}
}
@mixin xlg-up {
  @media #{$xlg-up} {@content}
}
*/
```

Comment: can you show us the error, and the related comment?

Comment: OK, just added it in my question!

Comment: Are you sure the problem is with the comment syntax and not the `$sm-breakpoint` variable, as the error says?

Comment: $sm-breakpoint variable is indeed undefined. But how is that a problem if it is mentioned within comments? There is something wrong here. What's in comments cannot trigger errors. At least I've never seen something like that before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SCSS has [two kinds of comments](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SCSS_FOR_SASS_USERS.html#comments):

> [SCSS] supports standard multiline CSS comments with `/* */`, which are preserved where possible in the output. These comments can have whatever formatting you like; Sass will do its best to format them nicely.
>
> SCSS also uses `//` for comments that are thrown away

Especially, SCSS interprets interpolated expressions (`#{..}`) within `/* */`. If you place the `$sm-xx` definitions into `//` style comments, the file will compile. (Note that you cannot nest comments. The `//` lines must be outside of the `/* */` block.)

Answer (score 1):

## Explaination

Sass supports standard multiline CSS comments with /* */, as well as single-line comments with //. The multiline comments are preserved in the CSS output where possible, while the single-line comments are removed. For example:

```
/* This comment is
 * several lines long.
 * since it uses the CSS comment syntax,
 * it will appear in the CSS output. */
body { color: black; }

// These comments are only one line long each.
// They won't appear in the CSS output,
// since they use the single-line comment syntax.
a { color: green; }
```

is compiled to:

```
/* This comment is
 * several lines long.
 * since it uses the CSS comment syntax,
 * it will appear in the CSS output. */
body {
  color: black; }

a {
  color: green; }
```

Another example

```
$version: "1.2.3";
/* This CSS is generated by My Snazzy Framework version #{$version}. */
```

is compiled to:

```
/* This CSS is generated by My Snazzy Framework version 1.2.3. */
```

Source: http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#comments

## Answer

this is why its trying to resolve variables inside your `/* */` and giving errors. to avoid this, use `//` instead.